# Uniqueness of connected sum

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Connected sum is defined as [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum) .But I think the result of connected sum is not unique. For example ,make connected sum on $S^2$ with itself . Then , the result can be $T^2$ or Klein bottle. Is it really so ?

If it is right , why it is not be declared which kind the connected sum is ?

Because my English is very poor, so I add a picture ,although it is very rough, but maybe it is useful to understand what I confuse.

> [image]

Comment: The connected sum of $S^2$ with itself is $S^2$ again.

Comment: @Crostul  I don't mean make connected sum of $S^2$ with $S^2$. Just one $S^2$ make connected sum .

Comment: @Crostul The $S^2$ make connected sum with itself. Not with another $S^2$.

Comment: @coffeemath But ,seemly, there are different ways to glue the boundary ,and there are any declare which way is chosen .

Comment: Probably, the result is unique up to homeomorphism or diffeomorphism if you work with smooth manifolds.

Comment: @Epsilon  Obviously , $T^2$ and Klein bottle are not homeomorphism .

Comment: I'm having extreme difficulty understanding what your post and comments say. You might be having difficulty with the vocabulary. The connected sum is indeed well-defined up to homeomorphism or diffeomorphism (depending on whether you're taking the connected sum of topological or smooth manifolds) though this is not trivial; for topological manifolds, well-definedness wasn't known in full generality until 1982. If I'm understanding your comments right, you're not talking about connected summing two disjoint manifolds, which is what everyone means when they say "well-definedness of connected...

Comment: ...sum"; the worry is that by picking a different disc to delete etc you'll get a different manifold. The connected sum operation should take as inputs manifolds $M, N$ and output a new, hopefully well-defined manifold $M \# N$, by deleting discs from $M \sqcup N$. Though the operation "Delete two discs from $S^2$ and glue their boundaries together" does make sense and does give you a torus, it is not called the connected sum.

Comment: Probably you want to mean __autosum__ as defined in the book by W.P Thurston

Comment: Google "Autosum Thurston"

Comment: And yes the operation does depend on the chosen homeomorphism of boundary sphere and hence result is not necessarily unique

Comment: @MikeMiller  Sorry ,my English is very poor .So I have added a picture in my question .  Besides, could you tell me the name of reference you mentioned?

Comment: @Neel   Thanks ,seemly ,the connected sum connects two disjoint manifold, so ,my example is not connected sum .

Comment: @MikeMiller   You are right , there must be two disjoint manifold. Beside, what mean is the $M \sqcup N$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The connected sum of two manifolds $M$ and $N$ (if either is orientable, orient it) is, by definition, the following operation.

Pick embeddings $\iota_M, \iota_N: D^n \to M, N$. If the manifolds are smooth, pick these to be smooth embeddings that agree with the oreintations of $M$ and $N$, when defined. Otherwise pick them to be locally flat embeddings. Choosing these embeddings provide diffeomorphisms $f_M: S^{n-1} \to \partial(M - \text{int } \iota_M(D^n))$, and similarly with $N$; we may then define $M \# N$ to be the manifold obtained by gluing the disjoint union of $M - \text{int } \iota_M(D^n)$ and $N - \text{int } \iota_N(D^n)$ by the homeomorphism/diffeomorphism of the boundary $f_N \circ f_M^{-1}$.

When you ask whether this is well-defined, you're asking whether taking two manifolds (if neither are non-orientable, both have fixed given orientations; I'm being careful about this because it matters! $\Bbb{CP}^2 \# \Bbb{CP}^2$ and $\Bbb{CP}^2 \# \overline{\Bbb{CP}^2}$ are different manifolds.) and doing this disc nonsense gives you a well-defined output manifold $M \# N$, independent of the choice of disc. This is not easy! Smale proved this in the smooth case in the 60s, and in the topological case it's resolved using what's called the annulus conjecture, resolved only in full generality in 1982.

What you're actually writing about in your post is not connected sum. The connected sum of two copies of $S^2$ (each with either orientation) is $S^2$ again (with some orientation). What you were doing is apparently denoted the "autosum" (see the comments), as you're deleting *two discs* inside one manifold $M$, as opposed to deleting discs in two different manifolds. This is always isomorphic to either $M \# S^{n-1} \times S^1$ if the two discs you embed for this process have the same orientation; and $M \# (S^{n-1} \tilde \times S^1)$ if they have different orientation. Here $S^{n-1} \tilde \times S^1 = S^{n-1} \times [0,1]/(x,0) \sim (r(x),1)$ is the twisted product of $S^{n-1}$ and $S^1$, and $r$ is the reflection across some hyperplane; for $n=2$ this gives the Klein bottle.

Comment: Mike, do you have a reference for the fact that $M\# N$ is well-defined if $M$ and $N$ are (not necessarily orientable) topological manifolds? I know Quinn proved the four-dimensional case of the annulus conjecture, but I couldn't find a discussion of the well-definedness of the connected sum operation in that paper.